# Dynamically change Quill placeholder

Tags: quill

I know that on instantiation of a Quill editor, there is a placeholder option. Is there a way that I can change this placeholder dynamically after the editor is instantiated?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The placeholder is implemented with a CSS rule:

```
.ql-editor::before { 
   content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
```

So you can do `quill.root.dataset.placeholder = 'Your new placeholder';`

Comment: For other people who see this, can you specify what `quill` is referring to in `quill.root.dataset.placeholder`? It took me a moment to realize that was my editor instance, since I did not name it `quill`.

Comment: this is the correct answer, thanks a ton, saved me a lot of headache

Comment: I need to do this same requirement using Angular 8. Can anyone please point me to certain blog to understand on how I can do this! I'm not clear yet with Quill Editor, still understanding.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using react-quill**

The placeholder in the tooltip is coming from the value of the `data-link` attribute. So you can replace the value with your own when the component finishes mounting.

Here is the code:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    //Replcae link in placeholder to your own text
    document.querySelector('.ql-tooltip-editor input').setAttribute("data-link", "your own placeholder");
}
```

*Note: I am using bubble theme*