# ngx quill placeholder not changing when selecting new language

Tags: angular, placeholder, quill, ngx-quill

For a school project we are using angular v4.4.6, ng2-translate for translations and ngx-quill@1.6.0 for text editor. When I use the placeholder attribute like so:

`<quill-editor placeholder="{{'Topic.new.quill-placeholder' | translate}}"...></quill-editor>`

Then my placeholder takes the value of the current language, but when I choose a new language my placeholder doesn't change. 
I have no idea why and wonder if there is a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Note: by now (7 month later) you should have found solution for this.

but what I think you're missing is setting the placeholder in box.

```
<quill-editor [placeholder]="'Topic.new.quill-placeholder'|translate"...></quill-editor>
```

that should solve the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided at [Dynamically change Quill placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936594/dynamically-change-quill-placeholder) works for me: 
`quill.root.dataset.placeholder = 'Your new placeholder';`

In Angular, your quill code maybe like this :

```
let editor = this.container.nativeElement.querySelector('#editor');
this.editor = new Quill(editor, {
              theme: 'snow',
              placeholder: this.placeholder
            });
```

your placeholder property maybe like this:

```
@Input()
get placeholder() {
   return this._placeholder;
}
set placeholder(plh) {
   this._placeholder = plh;
   this.stateChanges.next();
}
public _placeholder: string;
```

So what you need to do is to add some codes into property setter to update placeholder as follows:

```
set placeholder(plh) {
     this._placeholder = plh;
     this.stateChanges.next();    
     if (this.editor != null) {      
      this.editor.root.dataset.placeholder = this._placeholder;      
     }
  }
```